# What is the reason of taking batch size or number of neurons as a power of 2 in neural networks?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have seen many tutorials doing this and myself too have been adhering to this standard practice.

When it comes to batch size of a training data, we assign any value in geometric progression starting with 2 like 2,4,8,16,32,64.

Even when selecting the number of neurons in the hidden layers, we assign it the same way. Either of these - 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,...

What is the core reason behind this? Why does the neural network performs better doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use NVIDIA GPUs (the most popular choice for deep learning), the choice of channel size for convolutions and fully-connected layers mostly has to do with enabling Tensor cores, which as the name implies are used for efficient Tensor and matrix operations (and therefore for convolutions). To quote [the NVIDIA guide on performance for deep learning](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/dl-performance-guide/index.html):

> Choose the number of input and output channels to be divisible by 8 to enable Tensor Cores

Similar guidelines are given regarding batch size, however the reason for those is quantization.

Comment: so this mean, other number that are divisable by 8 are also valid ? The do not have to be a power of 2. So 24,40,48, etc are also valid ?